# Linux: how to check which handler is handling the signals

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel

The /proc/PID/status show that which signal is caught by the process. However, I wonder how to check which handler is handling the signal(s).
For example:

```
void  handler1(int sigNum)      
{
    if(sigNum == SIGINT)
        printf("handler1 is handling SIGINT\n");
} 

void  handler2(int sigNum)      
{
    if(sigNum == SIGINT)
        printf("handler2 is handling SIGINT\n");
} 

void main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, handler1);
    signal(SIGINT, handler2);
    while(1);
}
```

The main function has registered two signal handlers to handle the SIGINT. how to know handler1 or handler2 has been registered to handle SIGINT and is handling SIGINT?
I want to do the same thing just like psig under the Solaris.
[What is the meaning of every column when executing psig command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163573/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-column-when-executing-psig-command)

Comment: Do you want to determine the information from the command line, or from within the program?  From within the program, it is easy to determine the address of the function; determining the name that corresponds to that address is harder — even if the executable is compiled with debug information.  From outside the program (from the command line), I'm not sure what's feasible, short of attaching a debugger to the running process and arranging to stop it and interrogate the debugger.

Comment: I want to determine from the command line.

Comment: You’re going to need help from other people then. I’m not sufficiently familiar with the intimate details of `/proc` to be able to help much.  ‘Tis going to be fun mapping addresses to function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experimented with a monitoring program that executes a target process with `signal()`, `sigaction()`, and `fork()` interposed, using a dynamic helper library. The monitoring program listens for incoming Unix domain connections.

The dynamic library is very simple. At startup (using the GCC `constructor` attribute supported in Linux ELF binaries), it connects to the monitoring program. (After a successful `fork()`, the new process will close its copy of the descriptor, and open a new connection.) At each `signal()` or `sigaction()` invocation, it reports the signal name to the monitoring program using

```
struct change {
    uint64_t      addr;
    char          name[15];
    unsigned char info;       /* SA_RESETHAND; SIG_DFL/SIG_IGN */
};
```

The library maps signal numbers to names (like `SIGINT` to `"INT"`, or `SIGRTMIN+3` to `"RTMIN+3"`) or plain decimal number strings for unrecognized signal numbers.  This allows a single 64-bit monitoring program to monitor a mix of 64-bit and 32-bit processes.

The `info` field is used for reporting `SA_RESETHAND` (`SA_ONESHOT`) signal handlers, which get reset to default disposition when the signal is delivered to the handler. It is also used to indicate `SIG_DFL` and `SIG_IGN` handlers, plus possibly other special events.

When a new connection is made, the monitoring program uses `readelf -W --syms --dyn-syms` or `objdump -tT` or `objdump -d` on `/proc/PID/exe`, remembering the address (or address range) for each known function in the binary.  It logs each `struct change` for each connection, along with a timestamp.

(When a connection is made, the interposing library must "pause" until the monitoring program has examined the binary. Otherwise, short-running binaries may have exited (or executed another binary) before the monitoring program has had time to examine the correct binary.)

On my system, `bash` installs a `SIGCHLD` handler for address 447ad0, which does not have a symbol associated. If the known symbols are sorted in ascending order, and handlers are specified relative to the nearest symbol, then that handler could be reported as `reap_dead_jobs+40 <447ad0>`, for example. (Note that `reap_dead_jobs` resides at [447a90, 447ac1), so finding the symbol that covers the address will not suffice.)

Consider this a description of the approach that should work, based on my experiments. My own code needs a full rewrite to be useful; that is why I did not include it here. I'd expect the completed project to be around 600 - 900 lines of code.